# How to obtain random effects model matrix?

Tags: r, statistics, regression, lme4, mixed-models

I have a model such as:

```
mymod = lmer(y ~ x1 + x2 + (x1 | id) , data = mydata)
```

I know I can get the model matrix from the fitted object using `getME` but is there a way to obtain the model matrix for the fixed effects **without first fitting the model**:

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using the `lformula` function in the lme4 package. This rerurns an object which has holds the transpose of this matrix, `Zt`:

```
library(lme4)

# create some toy data
dt <- expand.grid(x1 = 1:4, x2 = 5:6, id = LETTERS[1:20], reps = 1:2)

# this is the model in the OP:
myFormula = "y ~ x1 + x2 + (x1 | id)"

# for lFormula to work we need y in the data frame
# so just put a vector of 1s since that will not affect the random effects model matrix:
dt$y <- 1
```

Then:

```
foo <- lFormula(eval(myFormula), dt)
Z <- t(as.matrix(foo$reTrms$Zt))
```

where `Z` is the model matrix for the random effects that you requested.

Answer (score 0):

Try `getME(lmer(y ~ x1 + x2 + (x1 | id) , data = mydata))`.

Comment: That requires fitting the model. They explicitly say they know about `GetME` and they want to create the matrix without fitting the model.

Comment: Oh well, I thought they meant not to store the model. I was mislead by _get_ _the_ _model_ _matrix_ _from_ _the_ _fitted_ _object_. My bad. I will wait for a comment from the author of this post, and then consider to delete my answer.

Comment: I dont think you should delete the asnwer. Google brought me here, even though I was searching for extraction from fitted model. By the way, you are missing the "name" argument. I think your answer should be `getME(model, name="Z")`, see [reference](https://rdrr.io/cran/lme4/man/getME.html).